# Remove 'On Hold' request

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

An OP seems to have put good effort in updating her question, but despite the question having been flagged to get moderator attention (I've requested the 'On Hold' be removed as it's now clear what the OP is asking for), but so far, the question is still on hold without having an opportunity to answer the OP.

The question I am referring to is: 
[How do I replace the phrase "As of when..."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311954/how-do-i-replace-the-phrase-as-of-when?noredirect=1#comment705582_311954)

Can this question be 'reopened?'

Comment: Only users with the required number of reputation points can cast their vote to reopen a post placed on hold. Sometimes a moderator, in his/her infinitive wisdom can single-handedly "release" these questions. Anyhoo, there are now three votes in favour, the question is much better than it originally was.

Comment: Related: [How often are questions re-opened?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/how-often-are-questions-re-opened) and [Request to reopen “Literal Meaning of 'Gosh'”](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2668/request-to-reopen-literal-meaning-of-gosh)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Thanks for the background info! I did find several related questions, as you also link to, but with my intention of actually requesting the removal of the on-hold, I figured it'd be best if I raised a new question altogether (as I did not know how else to bring the question under the attention of the moderator who put it on hold). Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason why the question should be reopened. This site is not an editing service and we're not here to suggest alternatives for authors.

If considered as a phrase request question rather than a proofreading question it is still very poor. It doesn't explain what is wrong with the existing option. It doesn't explain what is wrong with a simple "when".

Comment: Yet you edit the OP's post.... Anyways, if the OP would be aware of the option of using 'When', it might have been explained. As it is, I see more of a personal preference here than a convincing reason not to help the OP out. Perhaps it should be migrated to ELL then, if you feel ELU is too good for this sort of question.

Comment: @Terah Hi, Terah. I agree with curiousdannii. I don't think the question is reopenable. Is there even a question? I don't understand what the question is and why the OP wants to change the phrase. The question was not improved with the edit.

Comment: @Rathony - Hi Rathony, good to see you again. Well, the original question was a more vague before, and the edit provided context and whatnot. Arguably, the question is more suited for ELL, but I did, and still do, appreciate the way the OP responded to comments and put effort into turning the question into something more in line with how we like to see questions asked here. As for the why... well, I think the OP instinctively felt that something was wrong with the sentence, but lacked the skills to figure out what, why, and how to improve it. I'm sure there's a place for that here or at ELL?

Comment: @Terah It takes 5 votes to reopen it. It takes additional 5 votes to migrate it to ELL (unless a mod is involved). I feel it is quite time-consuming and unnecessary procedure. Still the question lacks context and reason why the OP needs to replace "as of when". I dbout the OP even understands what "as of when" means. Anyway, the questio is reopened. Your post worked!!! IMO, it is best to advise the OP to go to ELL where they belong.

Comment: And here I was looking for you on chat :) Well, heck, I was fine either way, but I do feel a bit like 'Let's reward a positive attitude!'. I can't see votes or anything yet, but the fact that 5 were given does indicate a bit of a chasm between the high(er) rep users when it comes to the age old 'what does/doesn't belong'.. Considering a recent discussion on ELL vs. ELU, I brainstormed a little, but I'll drop those thoughts in a meta post (so people can officially shoot it down :P)